# Get a number that follows a specified number and element

Tags: php, text, find, cpu-word, substr

I want to search in a string for an unknown value. For example, I want to search in the string "1:54,2:22,3:21" for the number that follows "2:". So I want "22" for my result. This is the code I've  written:

```
$card_session_items = "1:54,2:22,3:21";
$item_id = "2";
$isit = substr($card_session_items, strrpos( $card_session_items, "$item_id:"));
```

But this code's result is "22,3:21". How can I get just "22"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are doing but this may work for you.

```
array preg_split ( string $pattern , string $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int $flags = 0 ]] )

$output = $preg_split('(/,2:/)', "1:54,2:22,3:21", 2); 

echo $output[0] //will return '1:54';
echo $output[1] //will return '22,3:21';

$desire = $preg_split('(/,/)', $output[1], 2);

>$desire[0] = '22'
```